# Разница в спецификаторах шаблонов для регулярных выражений

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

Знаю, что в python существует несколько основных спецификаторов для регулярных выражений, некоторые из которых работаю идентично, но их запись отлична. Хотелось бы разобраться в специфике работы каждого из смущающих спецификаторов.
Я нашёл идентичными следующие из них:
1) prev? и prev*? 2) prev+? и prev 3) prev{m, n}? и prev{m}

Если брать функцию findall() из модуля re, возвращающую список, то при работе с источником

```
source = 'djs182291kcjd112ck8299jc1'
```

И регулярным выражением \d, результаты будут одинаковыми в 2 и 3 случаях, но не совсем таковыми с 1 случаем, хотя также будут выводиться отдельные цифры, но с большим количеством пустых строк. Буду благодарен за разьяснения.

Comment: То есть, просто почитать документацию по регулярным выражениям вы не хотите? Или вы ее уже прочитали, но что-то осталось для вас неясным?

Comment: Что у Вас обозначает `prev`? Слово `prev` или какой-то один символ или что-то ещё?

Comment: @Sergey Nudnov prev означает любое корректное регулярное выражение